# Trick to fix gst rounding issue -- why does it work?

Tags: math-software

In our system, we store prices ex-gst (without gst) and not inc-gst (with gst).The gst in my country is `10%`.

For example, if a product has an inc-gst price of `$9.95`, we store it as `$9.05`. The `$9.05` is calculated like this:
`$9.95/1.1 = $9.04545454545`. 
We then round-up `9.04545454545` to 2 decimal places, to get `$9.05`.

The problem is, when we want put the gst back into the price, it doesn't work:
`$9.05 * 1.1 = $9.955`, which results in `$9.96` when we round-up to 2 decimal places.

There is code in my system which apparently fixes this problem, but I don't understand why it works, or if it works in 
all cases. Here is the pseudo-code

```
inc_gst_price = round_up_to_2_decimal_places(ex_gst_price*1.1)
inc_gst_price = inc_gst_price * 100

if the last digit of inc_gst_price   == 9
     inc_gst_price +=  1
else if the last digit of inc_gst_price == 4
     inc_gst_price +=  1
else if the last digit of inc_gst_price == 1
     inc_gst_price -= 1
else if the last digit of inc_gst_price == 6
     inc_gst_price -= 1          

inc_gst_price = inc_gst_price / 100
```

The above code turns `$9.96` into `$9.95`. Which is correct.

Comment: Obviously, it will work perfectly if the pre-tax price is a multiple of $10$ cents, so you just have to check what happens to the last digit.

Comment: @JoshG Note this works because your GST rate is currently $10$%. However, it will often fail if this rate ever changes, e.g., goes to $9$% or $11$%.